# Alamofire 3.0 and swift 2.0 broke my APIWrapper

Tags: api, serialization, swift2, alamofire

I recently updated to swift 2.0 and it destroyed my alamofire serializer and API wrapper.

```
extension Alamofire.Request {
class func authResponseSerializer() -> Serializer {
    return {request, response, data in
        if data == nil {
            return (nil, nil)
        }
        var jsonError: NSError?
        let jsonData:AnyObject?
        do {
            jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])
        } catch var error as NSError {
            jsonError = error
            jsonData = nil
        } catch {
            fatalError()
        }
        if jsonData == nil || jsonError != nil {
            return (nil, jsonError)
        }
        let json = JSON(jsonData!)
        if json.error != nil || json == nil {
            return (nil, json.error)
        }

        var auth:Authorization = Authorization(json: json)
        return (auth, nil)
    }

 }

  func responseAuthorization(completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, Result<Authorization>) -> Void) -> Self {
      return response(responseSerializer: Request.authResponseSerializer(), completionHandler: completionHandler)
 }
```

in the request extension i get the error

and in the second func responseAuthoriztion

Use of undeclared type 'Serializer'

I get the error generic type Result specialized with too few type parameters (got 1, but expected 2)

How do i migrate my code to alamofire 3.0 and swift 2.0? I've been reading the migration guides and can't figure this out, many other people I'm sure are dealing with this same problem.

Comment: In Alamofire 3.0, the Result type has been redesigned to be a double generic type , so your Result<Authorization> should be Result<Authorization, Error>. There is no Serializer now only ResponseSerializer<Value, Error>